# Make my laptop and desktop under same network connected by my mobile phone via usb tethering and hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, reverse-tethering

I need to make my laptop and desktop under same network wirelessly .Both are connected to internet using my mobile phone , laptop using the hotspot and the desktop using the usb tethering , since my desktop is not having an inbuilt wifi module . Any way to do it??
Thanks

Comment: Does your laptop have an Ethernet Port?

Comment: @El8tedN8te , currently I connected my laptop to my phones hotspot and connected to desktop via ethernet and bridged this ethernet and wifi. But with this I cannot move around with my laptop, it need to be connected with desktop via ethernet.

Comment: So you want to do all this without bridging the ethernet cable from the Laptop to the Desktop, but contradictorily you say "it [the laptop????] need to be connected with desktop via ethernet." Please clarify yourself.

Comment: @El8tedN8te , its my current situation bro , don't want that .

Comment: I'm aware that you don't want that but you contradicted yourself with that last bit of the sentence "it needs to be connected with desktop via network". In which, if not the laptop, a router?????????